# Is there any way of combining Wikipedia comparisons into a single table?

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki

Take, for example, this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools

It's typical of most Wikipedia comparison pages, with the information split across multiple individual tables - if I want to compare GPL tools, it's not enough to sort the first table by license - it doesn't affect the others.

I want to have a single table so I can sort/filter/compare more easily.

Is anyone aware of an existing tool that does this?

Answer (score 1):

I made a [little script](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffSLOfish/A2CYN/) for you that will do just this. You currently have to paste the html for the tables in question into the **HTML** window, but after you do that just hit **Run** and you will see the combined tables. If you would like something more advanced, please let me know.